# Limit Bootstrap3 .panel-collapse to the height of it's contianer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can limit the height of .panel-collapse like this:

```
.panel-collapse {
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

But I want the panel to fit exactly the size of the screen in my single page application. The body is the limiting container. How do I do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/LmLp5ovm/